# Survey123 form not updating

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I have created a survey form using Survey123 connect. As I have been using it in the field, I have found that some updates to the question directions/hints/descriptions will be helpful for accurate data collection.

I have updated the text for these in the XLS form through Survey123 connect. However, when I go to save and publish, no changes are made to the form (the one in Survey123 connect, on AGOL, or on the field devices). I am only making changes to the labels or hint columns, not to the data/question type, etc.

Why is this not updating and what I can do to make the updates? Preferably without needing to make a copy of the survey and publishing it as a separate survey.

Comment: Have you logged into AGOL on the collection device and downloaded the updated survey?

Comment: Is it giving you any errors when publishing from Connect?

Comment: Yes, I have logged into AGOL on the collection device and updated the survey. However, the update doesn't change anything. 

And, no errors when I publish it.